# GLSL - a shader does not work using mediump precision

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl

I have a shader of atmospheric scattering that I found through the Internet. In fact, this is the WebGL(three.js) shader. I try to run it on mobile devices. I found out that it works great on `Qualcomm` and `KIRIN` chipsets when I use `hihgp` precision and doesn't work on `Mali` chipsets at all (just black screen). Athouth, it compiles without any errors. I assume that this happens because `Mali` GPUs (or similar ones) have not enough `highp` precision for this shader. If I use mediump precision it doesn't work on all devices (just black screen). Is it possible to make this(any) shader works using `mediump` precision? Or how to make this shader works on all popular chipsets?

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n"+         

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

void main() {               
  vec4 worldPosition = u_worldTrans * vec4( a_position, 1.0 );
  vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
  gl_Position = u_projTrans * worldPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;  
#endif 

uniform vec3 sunPosition;

varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

const float turbidity = 3.2; 
const float reileigh = 2.7; 
const float luminance = 1.0; 
const float mieCoefficient = 0.007; 
const float mieDirectionalG = .990; 

#define e 2.718281828459 
#define pi 3.141592653589 

#define n 1.0003

#define pn 0.035

const vec3 lambda = vec3(0.00000068, 0.00000055, 0.00000045); 

const vec3 K = vec3(0.686, 0.678, 0.666); 

const vec3 up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 

#define v 4.0 

#define rayleighZenithLength 8400.0 
#define mieZenithLength 1250.0 

#define EE 1000.0 
#define sunAngularDiameterCos 0.999956676946 

#define cutoffAngle pi/1.95 
#define steepness 1.5 


vec3 simplifiedRayleigh()
{
    return 0.0005 / vec3(94., 40., 18.);
}

float rayleighPhase(float cosTheta)
{    
    return (3.0 / (16.0*pi)) * (1.0 + pow(cosTheta, 2.0));          
}

vec3 totalMie(vec3 lambda, vec3 K, float T)
{
    float val = 10E-18; 
    float c = (0.2 * T ) * val;
    return 0.434 * c * pi * pow((2.0 * pi) / lambda, vec3(v - 2.0)) * K;
}

float hgPhase(float cosTheta, float g)
{           
    return (1.0 / (4.0*pi)) * ((1.0 - pow(g, 2.0)) / pow(abs(1.0 - 2.0*g*cosTheta + pow(g, 2.0)), 1.5));
}

float sunIntensity(float zenithAngleCos)
{
    return EE * max(0.0, 1.0 - exp(-((cutoffAngle - acos(zenithAngleCos))/steepness)));
}


#define A 0.15
#define B 0.50 
#define C 0.10 
#define D 0.20 
#define E 0.02 
#define F 0.30 
#define W 1000.0 
vec3 Uncharted2Tonemap(vec3 x)
{
   return ((x*(A*x+C*B)+D*E)/(x*(A*x+B)+D*F))-E/F;
}

void main() 
{

    vec3 cameraPos = vec3(0., 0., -500.);
    float sunfade = 1.0-clamp(1.0-exp((sunPosition.y/4000.0)),0.0,1.0);

    float reileighCoefficient = reileigh - (1.0* (1.0-sunfade));
    vec3 sunDirection = normalize(sunPosition);

    float sunE = sunIntensity(dot(sunDirection, up));

    vec3 betaR = simplifiedRayleigh() * reileighCoefficient;

    vec3 betaM = totalMie(lambda, K, turbidity) * mieCoefficient;

    float zenithAngle = acos(max(0.0, dot(up, normalize(vWorldPosition - cameraPos))));
    float sR = rayleighZenithLength / (cos(zenithAngle) + 0.15 * pow(abs(93.885 - ((zenithAngle * 180.0) / pi)), -1.253));
    float sM = mieZenithLength / (cos(zenithAngle) + 0.15 * pow(abs(93.885 - ((zenithAngle * 180.0) / pi)), -1.253));

    vec3 Fex = exp(-(betaR * sR + betaM * sM));

    float cosTheta = dot(normalize(vWorldPosition - cameraPos), sunDirection);

    float rPhase = rayleighPhase(cosTheta*0.5+0.5);
    vec3 betaRTheta = betaR * rPhase;

    float mPhase = hgPhase(cosTheta, mieDirectionalG);
    vec3 betaMTheta = betaM * mPhase;


    vec3 Lin = pow(abs(sunE * ((betaRTheta + betaMTheta) / (betaR + betaM)) * (1.0 - Fex)),vec3(1.5));
    Lin *= mix(vec3(1.0),pow(sunE * ((betaRTheta + betaMTheta) / (betaR + betaM)) * Fex,vec3(1.0/2.0)),clamp(pow(1.0-dot(up,sunDirection),5.0),0.0,1.0));

    vec3 L0 = vec3(0.1) * Fex;

    float sundisk = smoothstep(sunAngularDiameterCos,sunAngularDiameterCos+0.00002,cosTheta);

    L0 += (sunE * 19000.0 * Fex)*sundisk;

    vec3 whiteScale = 1.0/Uncharted2Tonemap(vec3(W));

    vec3 texColor = (Lin+L0);   
    texColor *= 0.04 ;
    texColor += vec3(0.0,0.001,0.0025)*0.3;

    vec3 curr = Uncharted2Tonemap((log2(2.0/pow(luminance,4.0)))*texColor);
    vec3 color = curr*whiteScale;

    vec3 retColor = pow(color,vec3(1.0/(1.2+(1.2*sunfade))));

    gl_FragColor.rgb = retColor;

    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

I'm using LibGDX, so my shader class is bellow:

```
public class SkyShader implements Shader{

ShaderProgram program;
Camera specCamera;
int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

int u_projTrans;
int u_worldTrans;

int u_sunPosition;
int u_res;

int u_luminance;
int u_turbidity;
int u_reileigh;
int u_mieCoefficient;
int u_mieDirectionalG;

public Vector3 sunDirection = new Vector3();

Matrix4 viewInvTraMatrix = new Matrix4();


@Override
public void init() {

    program = new ShaderProgram(vert, frag);    
    if (!program.isCompiled())throw new RuntimeException(program.getLog());

    else Gdx.app.log("sky program", "shader compiled successfully!");


    u_projTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_projTrans");
    u_worldTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_worldTrans");

    u_sunPosition = program.getUniformLocation("sunPosition");

    u_res = program.getUniformLocation("u_res");
}   



@Override
public void dispose() {
    if(program!=null){
        program.dispose();
        program = null;
    }
}

static final float delta = 0.0028526667f;

Matrix4 projectionMatrix = new Matrix4();

@Override
public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {               
    program.begin();

    projectionMatrix.set(camera.projection);        
    if(Settings.landscape)
        projectionMatrix.rotate(0, 1, 0, (Settings.EarthRotation-100) * .4f);       
    else projectionMatrix.rotate(0, 1, 0, (Settings.EarthRotation-100) * .7f);              
    program.setUniformMatrix(u_projTrans, projectionMatrix);        

    if(Settings.EnableSlightShadowGradient)
        program.setUniformf(u_res, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


    float rotation = Settings.EarthRotation * delta -.0375f;//- .00674f;
    float azimuth = rotation; //_azimuth;


    float inclination = .3f; //skyParams[i][4];
    float theta = (float) (Math.PI * ( inclination - 0.5f ));
    float phi = (float) (2f * Math.PI * ( azimuth - 0.5f ));

    float distance = 4000;//400000;
    sunDirection.x = (float) (distance * Math.cos( phi ));
    sunDirection.y = (float) (distance * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta ));
    sunDirection.z = (float) (distance * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta ));


    context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LEQUAL);   
    context.setCullFace(GL20.GL_FRONT);     
}


@Override
public boolean canRender(Renderable arg0) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Shader arg0) {     
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void end() {
    program.end();      
}



@Override
public void render(Renderable renderable) {     
    program.setUniformMatrix(u_worldTrans, renderable.worldTransform);

    program.setUniformf(u_sunPosition, sunDirection);

    renderable.mesh.render(program, renderable.primitiveType, 
            renderable.meshPartOffset, renderable.meshPartSize);
}

}
```

And finally, I render it using the following code:

```
modelBatch.begin(cam);  
modelBatch.render(sphere, skyShader);
modelBatch.end();
```

Where sphere is:

```
public ModelInstance createSphere() {
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

    float radius = 4500;//450000;

    Model tempSphere;
    tempSphere = modelBuilder.createSphere(radius, radius, radius, 32, 8,
            new Material(),
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates
    );

    return new ModelInstance(tempSphere,0,0,0);       
}
```

Original shader is [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_sky.html)

**EDIT**
If I run original shader(link is above) on `problem` devices in browser it works perfect!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to work out where the problem lies on a shader so complex, it might not even be precision that's the problem - it could be exceeding total instruction count, or negatives creeping into the left side of pow functions. If it is just precision, then the best approaches can be to move some heavy calculations onto the vertex shader and rely on interpolation (this may require subdividing your mesh further). Alternatively, use textures as lookup tables for some of the complex math.

Comment: Mali-400 series doesn't support highp in fragment shaders (it's an optional feature in OpenGL ES 2.x). Even if you get it working, this shader is pretty complex (~60 cycles a fragment for a Mali-400), so on most mass-market handsets with only two or three shader cores I suspect performance will be pretty poor. With 3 cores at 500Mhz running at 720p30 you only get 50 cycles a pixel ...

Comment: @solidpixel, @Columbo, Today I found out that webgl version of this shader works well on `problem` devices when I run it in browser! What's the difference between glsl & webgl then?